# Converting a MultiSet<E> object to object array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multiset, bag

I am working on collections of generic arrays`E[]`. I'm currently stuck on the union of two sets and trying to convert a `MultiSet<E> aSet` into a generic array. I'm trying to compare the generic array of the current class, or the 'this' array, to the one being accepted in the `union` method. Here is my current partition of code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public MultiSet<E> union(MultiSet<E> aSet) {

    MyBag<E> set = (MyBag<E>) aSet;
    E[] temp;
    temp = (E[]) new Keyed[2*length];
    // ...  
    return new MyBag<E>(temp);
}   // Generate the union of two bags.
```

Would gladly clarify any questions needed. Thank you

Comment: Where is `MultiSet` coming from?  Is it from some library?  Are you defining it yourself?

Comment: It's an ADT that I have been given and this class inherits the union.

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand, but it seems as if you can simply copy everything to the temp array with two for loops, one to copy the aSet in and the other to copy the 'this' array. Then the temp array would contain all the elements of each, and the new Bag would have everything. The way you currently have it set up though, aSet would have to have the same length as this.length

Comment: I want to take MultiSet<E> aSet, put it into an E[] and from there, go element by element comparing each to see if they are present in both. What you said about the for-loops is correct. I just don't know how to take a MultiSet<E> object and convert it into an E[]...I've tried different ways but always get a conversion error.